# Is there a pythonic way to update a dictionary value when the update is dependent on the value itself?

Tags: python

I find myself in a lot of situations where I have a dictionary value that I want to update with a new value, but only if the new value fulfils some criteria relative to the current value (such as being larger).

Currently I write expressions similar to:

```
dictionary[key] = max(newvalue, dictionary[key])
```

which works fine but I keep thinking that there's probably a neater way to do it that doesn't involve repeating myself.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: There's nothing unpythonic about `if [condition]: dictionary[key] = value`

Comment: An object-oriented way would be to derive a `dict` subclass that does what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write yourself a helper function:

```
def update(dictionary, key, newvalue, func=max):
    dictionary[key] = func(dictionary[key], newvalue)
```

Comment: I like this solution because it maintains the clarity of the code while still avoiding so much repetition.

Answer (score 3):

You could make the values objects with update methods that encapsulate that logic.  Or subclass dictionary and modify the behavior of `__setitem__`.  Just keep in mind anything you do like this is going to make it less clear to someone not familiar with your code what is going on.  What you are doing now is most explicit and clear.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's "neater", but one way to avoid repeating yourself is to use an object-oriented approach and subclass the built-in `dict` class to make something able to do what you want. This also has the advantage that instances of your custom class can be used in place of `dict` instances without changing the rest of your code.

```
class CmpValDict(dict):
    """ dict subclass that stores values associated with each key based
       on the return value of a function which allow the value passed to be
       first compared to any already there (if there is no pre-existing
       value, the second argument passed to the function will be None)
    """
    def __init__(self, cmp=None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.cmp = cmp if cmp else lambda nv,cv: nv  # default returns new value
        super(CmpValDict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        super(CmpValDict, self).__setitem__(key, self.cmp(value, self.get(key)))

cvdict = CmpValDict(cmp=max)

cvdict['a'] = 43
cvdict['a'] = 17
print cvdict['a']  # 43

cvdict[43] = 'George Bush'
cvdict[43] = 'Al Gore'
print cvdict[43]  # George Bush
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using the Python version of a ternary operator:

```
d[key]=newval if newval>d[key] else d[key]
```

or a one line if:

```
if newval>d[key]: d[key]=newval
```